# Create a Pivot Table of Two Categorical and Numerical Variables

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I have the following hypothetical dataframe

```
Region <- c("District A", "District B","District A","District A","District B")
Gender <- c("Male","Male","Female", "Male","Female")
Age <- c(20, 21, 23, 34, 22)
AmountSold <- c(50, 10, 20, 4, 12)
RegionSales <- data.frame(Region, Gender, Age, AmountSold)
```

I'd like to create a pivot table or a table that shows both mean of Amount sold per gender and Region as well as the mean of Age per gender and region. How do I do that in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be my approach with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

RegionSales %>%
  group_by(Region, Gender) %>%
  summarize(mean_age = mean(Age), mean_amount = mean(AmountSold))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Region [2]
  Region     Gender mean_age mean_amount
  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 District A Female       23          20
2 District A Male         27          27
3 District B Female       22          12
4 District B Male         21          10
```

An option that ignores `NA` values:

```
RegionSales %>%
  group_by(Region, Gender) %>%
  summarize(mean_age = mean(Age, na.rm = T),
            mean_amount = mean(AmountSold, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this with a data frame similar to the structure but on the summary statistics, I get NA's instead of values associated with measures of central tendency. What could be the issue? My DF has NA values

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`, another option is to specify the variables in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
RegionSales %>%
    group_by(Region, Gender) %>%
    summarise(across(c(Age, AmountSold),
             ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .names = "mean_{.col}"))
```

Comment: What if I'd like to add other measures of central tendency such as median, min, max and range. How do I go about that?

Comment: @Muli that is easy, just do `summarise(across(c(Age, AmountSold), list(mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), median = ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE), min = ~ min(., na.rm = TRUE), max = ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE)))` `range` is actually min/max

Answer (score 2):

A base option using `aggregate` could help

```
> aggregate(. ~ Region + Gender, RegionSales, mean)
      Region Gender Age AmountSold
1 District A Female  23         20
2 District B Female  22         12
3 District A   Male  27         27
4 District B   Male  21         10
```